# Javascript can disable/enable buttons but can't disable radio buttons or text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap

I am making a phonegap app and I have a page which requires some user input. If a checkbox (reported) is checked then I want to disable all user input except the next check button.

```html
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="MainBody">
  <ul id="topBtns">
    <li id="reportedLabel">
      <label id="reportedLabel">
        <input type="checkbox" id="reported" class="hidden" onchange="document.getElementById('1a').disabled = this.checked;document.getElementById('1b').disabled = this.checked;document.getElementById('comment1').disabled = this.checked;document.getElementById('photo1').disabled = this.checked;">
        Already reported
      </label>
    </li>
    <li id="back">
      <button id="back" data-icon="arrow-l">
        Check 0
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <h2 class="checkNum">Check #1</h2>
  <p class="check">Some Text</p>
  <label><input type="radio" id="1a" name="1">Answer1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" id="1b" name="1">Answer2</label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Type your comments here" id="comment1"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="photo1" onclick="insert_photo()">
    Insert Photo
  </button>
  <button id="btnCont1" onClick="location.href='index.html#Q2'">Continue</button>
</div> <!-- Main -->
```

It works when I run the code on the snippet in this question but when I run it through the phonegap app or even just run the HTML file only the insert photo button gets disabled but the other 3 elements are ignored. This makes me think that it has something to do with Jquery Mobile but I'm not sure to be completely honest.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: It seems to work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kz8j56aq/1/

Comment: @mpora yeah it worked for me but as soon as I put it into phonegap it refused to work properly

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Also make sure to **add all script and their references at index.html page.**

Comment: I'm just using jquery mobile straight from their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't test in your environment, it's probably related to the way you're using `this`. In order to better examine your problem I tranfered the code on onchange event to a function. The first problem I had was that `this` wasn't being passed to the function. Then I initially called the function like `disableControls(this.checked)`, and using a parameter to get the value. It worked but made me think that could be your problem. The best would be for you to try to get the checked value using document.getElementById also. 
Take a look at my example and reproduce in your environment to see if it works.
If it don't you can use console.log the elements to debug what's wrong.

```js
function disableControls() {  
    var checked = document.getElementById('reported').checked;
    document.getElementById('1a').disabled = checked;
    document.getElementById('1b').disabled = checked;
    document.getElementById('comment1').disabled = checked;
    document.getElementById('photo1').disabled = checked; 
}
```

```html
<html >
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="MainBody">
 <ul id="topBtns">
  <li id="reportedLabel">
   <label id="reportedLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" id="reported" class="hidden" onchange="disableControls();">
    Already reported
   </label>
  </li>
  <li id="back"><button id="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Check 0</button></li>
 </ul>
 <br>
 <h2 class="checkNum">Check #1</h2>
 <p class="check">Some Text</p>
 <label><input type="radio" id="1a" name="1">Answer1</label>
 <label><input type="radio" id="1b" name="1">Answer2</label>
 <br>
 <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Type your comments here" id="comment1"></textarea>
 <br>
 <button id="photo1" onclick="insert_photo()">Insert Photo</button>
 <button id="btnCont1" onClick="location.href='index.html#Q2'">Continue</button>
</div> <!-- Main -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try that first thing tomorrow morning. How would I use document.getElementById to retrieve the check value?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that in the first line of the `disableControls()` function.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Much appreciated

Comment: I just tried your solution and it did exactly the same thing where it disabled the button but didn't disable the text area or inputs. It's worth noting that if I manually give the text area the disabled attribute it works just not in javascript. This is definitely a jquery mobile issue because as soon as I removed jquery mobile it worked fine

Comment: It turned out to be a jquery mobile issue because they use different syntax so I used $(#1a).attr('disabled', 'disabled');  thanks for all the help